# PostgreSQL collapse multiple rows as one custom named

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to collapse multiple rows in PostgreSQL.
I'm counting the 'page views' of specific pages in a web application over the last month.

```
SELECT DISTINCT page_urlpath AS "URL",
COUNT(DISTINCT (domain_userid)) AS "Unique views"
FROM "atomic".events
WHERE derived_tstamp > current_date - integer '31'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Output would look something like this:

```
/title/342fer243r
/title/1rf3f134r4
/title/141f14r1tr
```

And I would like to end up with:

```
/title/subtitle
```

I'm unsure how to perfect my query to collapse all rows with

```
/title/*
```

into just one custom named row.

** UPDATE **

I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Regexp_replace( page_urlpath, 'title/(*)', 'title/subtitle' ) AS "URL", 
                Count(DISTINCT (domain_userid))                        AS "Unique views" 
FROM            "atomic".events 
WHERE           derived_tstamp > CURRENT_DATE - integer '31' 
GROUP BY        1 
ORDER BY        2 DESC ;
```

But I know that the "all" part doesn't work. `'title/(*)',`. Any good ideas?

Comment: Do you **always** want to take the first element of the URL? Also: `current_date - integer '31'` can be simplified to `current_date - 31`

Comment: I would like to collapse and rename all the '4h23u5hi4' into something more meaningful. Would not really need the first element of the URL.

Comment: Let me re-phrase my question: is the relevant part **only** the first part or can it be first part for some URLs, the first and second for others, and the first, second and third for yet another set of URLs?

Comment: Well the last part of the URL is also very relevant here. e.g. /title/ is one site, but /title/398fre23 and /title/kfn3234 are just as important in my count here. I would just like to "group" all the h34kj24 into one /title/details maybe, and count all occurrences as one URL. Does it make sense? :)

Comment: Your regex is a little out.   Instead of "title/(\*)" use "title/(.\*)"   The ".*" means match 0 or more 'anythings'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is have a mapping table that maps url patterns to the page you want to report on.  This can be a CTE if you don't want to create an actual database table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
page_url varchar,
derived_tstamp timestamp,
domain_userid int);

insert into events values 
('/title/item1',current_timestamp,1),
('/title/item1',current_timestamp,2),
('/title/item2',current_timestamp,3),
('/title/item3',current_timestamp,1),
('/home/user1',current_timestamp,1),
('/home/user2',current_timestamp,2),
('/home/user3',current_timestamp,3),
('/order/order1',current_timestamp,1),
('/order/order2',current_timestamp,1);


WITH pages (prefix,page) AS (
VALUES ('/title/','/title/subtitle'),
        ('/home/','Home Page'),
        ('/order/','/order/*')
)
SELECT
  pages.page as "Page",
  count(distinct (domain_userid)) as "Unique Views"
FROM
  events e
  INNER JOIN pages ON LEFT(page_url, LENGTH(pages.prefix)) = pages.prefix
WHERE
  derived_tstamp > current_date - 31
GROUP BY pages.page
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Here the pages CTE maps prefixes '/title/','/home/' etc, to a page name that we're going to show in the results.

It does a simple string comparison to check if the url matches the prefix, and if so uses that name instead of the url.

This does have the side effect that any URL that doesn't match any pattern won't show up though.

Fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d6279/3

Comment: I've added the table definition I'm using.  Fiddle seems down at moment so can't create it there.  The query has ha the atomic namespace removed so it runs against the events table in default schema.

Comment: I've added a fiddle to demonstrate